# ML Regressor model performance conclusion RSME vs STD DEV

Tags: regression, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow

Perhaps my question is still slightly silly but apparently even though lot of folks talk about how to evaluate the rightness of your model there still blur the right evaluation procedure at least for me.

I know that a good indicator about model performance on regression models is catch the `RMSE` as measure, in theory as much this number decrease after every training iteration my model is learning therefore is going well.

However, I would like to through a conclusion like this model is good enough because the the `RMSE` is ideal. I have found thru few post and readings that I might be able to compare the `RSME` against the target column standard deviation for the same train dataset used to get the `RMSE` and then as much closer my `RSME` will be of the target column standard deviation then my model is better. I that right guys?

PDS: Please try to simplify the answers in non deep maths or stats arguments I'm only a data engineer so perhaps there is a high lack of background that will make harder to understand you. well appreciated.

thanks so much

Comment: If the target column is, for example,  sine wave data then the standard deviation might be much higher than the RMSE of a good sine wave fit. Consider the RMSE as a sort of "average magnitude of error", as the fitting errors are first squared (making all values positive), then the mean (or average)  of those values is calculated, and finally the square root of this mean value is taken. This was given the name Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE) for this reason.

Comment: Thanks James but then the answer you give is yes or not? if not `RSME` vs Standard deviation then what should I do to know how great is the model?  thanks

Comment: There is no single fit statistic that works in every case, because there are different reasons for modeling data. If what you want to have a good understanding of the average magnitude of the regression errors, use RMSE. If you want to understand what fraction of the dependent data variance is explained by the model, use R-squared. If you want to know the worst-case predicted error, use maximum or minimum error value. Which one to choose depends on the purpose of the model. In other cases the interest is in the percentage errors, I have seen this also.